# Pandas and NLTK: Replace empty cells with subsring of adjacent column, if substring is contained in NLTK tokens

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have a table consisting of PRODUCT NAMEs and MAKERs. Some of the maker cells are empty hence i want to write a code to replace the empty cells in maker column with the substring in the product names. here is the table for info:

[image]

In order to identify the substrings i want to use, iam using NLTK library.

here is the code i have written so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


a=('Nokia 3518','Nokia 3313','Samsung S9','Samsung S10','Samsung S4')
b=('Nokia','','','Samsung','')

df=pd.DataFrame({'Product Name':(a) , 'Maker':(b)})
df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)


result = [' '.join([row for row in df['Product Name']])]

result=str(result).replace("'",'')

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(result)
#iam taking only words greater than 4 letters

longwords= [wrd for wrd in tokens if len(wrd)>4] #Words containing 3 letters or less will be 
removed

print(longwords)

#keeping words only that occur more than once and putting it in a dataframe
fdist = FreqDist(longwords)
x=list(filter(lambda x: x[1]>1,fdist.items())) 
print(x)

# putting the tokens in a dataframe (Nokia and Samsung)
dfb=pd.DataFrame(x)

print(dfb[0])
```

So far i have written the code to generate the tokens however iam not sure how to move on from here.

ultimately, i want to append the dataframe to be as follows by allowing the code to match substrings in Product Name with the items in the tokens dataframe(dfb) and appending maker column accordingly:

[image]

Comment: why not just use a regular expression ? `df['Maker'].fillna(df['Product Name'].str.extract('(\D.*?)\s')[0])`

Comment: THanks for your feedback guys. i used the nltk because i want only to fillna with substrings from 'Product Name' column that have more than 4 letter and occurs more than once. (original table is much bigger, i just simplified it above with 5 rows shown)Not sure how to incorporate that in regex. is there a way to do it using pandas and nltk. perhaps beggining as such:     for i in df['Maker']:
    if pd.isnull(i):
        if any(x in ['Product Name'] for y in dfb[0]):
            ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest answer i found to add to original code::

```
z=[]
for i in df['Product Name']:
    for j in dfb[0]:
        if j in i:
            z.append(j)

df['Maker']=z

print(df)
```